# Screen is not changing in kivymd showing "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transition' "

Tags: kivy, screen, python-3.7, kivy-language

I have two classes inherited from the screen. In the main screen, there is a navigation drawer from which I want to change my screen to another screen but when I try to do that it throws an Attribute error saying NoneType object has no attribute 'transition' I have tried everything here's the code of my .kv file

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManager:
    id: screens

    FirstScreen:
        Share:

    AboutUs:
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'close'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.97}
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release:
                screens.transition.direction = 'right'
                screens.current = "main"

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    background_color: 2, 3, 4, 5
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

        MDLabel:
            anchor_y: 'left'
            text: "[b]Story A Day[/b]"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            markup: True
            font_style: "H4"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: 'Story A Day'
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            MDExpansionPanelTwoLine:
                text: 'send us your idea'
                secondary_text: 'email: xxxxx@gmail.com'

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "email"

            TwoLineAvatarListItem:
                text: 'Send us'
                secondary_text: 'to: Story@gmail.com'

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "email"

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text: "About Us"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screens.transition.direction = 'right'
                    root.screens.current = "screen1"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "information"
                    on_release:
                        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        app.root.manager.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.5)
                        app.root.manager.current = "screen1"

<AboutUs>:
    name: 'screen1'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text_color: 255, 255, 255, 0
        text: """[b]About Us [/b]"""
        markup: True
        font_size: '40sp'
        text_size: None, None
        size_hint: 1, 1.9
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    Label:
        text_color: 255, 255, 255, 0
        font_size: '18sp'
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: 1, 1.5
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        halign: "center"
        valign: "center"
        text:
            """ """

<Share>:
    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        data: root.data
        icon: 'share-variant'
        opening_time: 0.5
        callback: root.callback   # on pressing the call stack buttons
        color_icon_root_button: 0, 0, 0, 1  # color of icon of button
        color_icon_stack_button: 0, 0, 0, 1
        hint_animation: True
        rotation_root_button: False


<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout

        ScreenManager:
            id: screens
            Screen:

                MDToolbar:
                    id: toolbar
                    title: "Story"
                    anchor_title: 'left'
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]


                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: root.height - toolbar.height
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    ScrollView:
                        Label:
                            text:
                                """
                                A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy
                                had a collection of marbles. The girl has some
                                sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he
                                would give her all his marbles in exchange for the
                                sweets with her. The girl agreed.

                                The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest
                                marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles.
                                The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised.
                                That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy
                                could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl
                                has hidden some sweets from him the way he had
                                hidden the best marbles from her.

                                Moral of the Story :

                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                """
                            font_size: '20sp'
                            text_color: 255,255,255, 0
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text_size: root.width, None
                            size_hint_x: 1.0
                            size_hint_y: None
                            halign: "center"
                            valign: "middle"



        MDNavigationDrawer:
            title: 'Story A Day'
            id: nav_drawer
            swipe_distance: 10

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
                screens: app.root
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write app.root.screens.current inside the on_release everywhere that's all